# Removing knox from my phone

Tags: samsung-knox

I am trying to reuse my samsung galaxy j3 prime phone which i havent used in a while i have some things i want to get off of it as well. My problem is that i have knox on my phone which i hide with my important apps and files. I cant rememeber how to get into or even find where it's hinding in order to get into the app. Alone with the fact that i cant rememeber my longin information. Is there anyway to make it show up so i can get inside my account?

Answer (score 1):

try to disable KNOX by typing `pm disable --user 0 com.sec.knox.seandroid` in adb shell. When uninstalling KNOX, you are asked if you want to backup your KNOX data

Comment: Ok i will try that but im not really even sure what you said. But i think i can figure that out. Im new at all this i wanna learn but cant seem to rapped my head around all if it. Like a dog chasing its tail. I also cant even access root. Bbc agent im guessing has it locked down.

Comment: I tried that it didnt work